# WebSphere Liberty Profile blocking on Datasource lookup

Tags: configuration, datasource, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to configure a datasource in IBM WebSphere Liberty Profile (16.0.0.3) and this is what I've done so far:

**server.xml**

```
<authData id="dbuser" password="{xor}blablabla" user="MY_USER"/>

<dataSource id="Oracle" isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED" 
    jdbcDriverRef="OracleDriver" 
    jndiName="EPMS_DS" 
    recoveryAuthDataRef="dbuser" 
    type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource">

    <properties.oracle databaseName="DBNAME" portNumber="1521" serverName="SERVERNAME"/>
</dataSource>

<jdbcDriver id="OracleDriver" 
    javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource" 
    libraryRef="shared-library"/>
```

**web.xml**

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <description>The Oracle DS</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/OracleDS</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

**ibm-web-bnd.xml**

```
<resource-ref name="jdbc/OracleDS" binding-name="EPMS_DS">
    <authentication-alias name="dbuser" />
</resource-ref>
```

However, besides the application server is taking more than 2 minutes to startup, my application seems to freeze on the following instruction:

```
ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/OracleDS");
```

The log doesn't show any errors, the last line it shows is an application's debug message indicating it is going to do a JNDI lookup.

I've also tried different configurations in `server.xml`, without `<authData>` and explicitly defining user and password on the datasource, but with identical results:

```
<dataSource id="Oracle" isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED" jdbcDriverRef="OracleDriver" jndiName="EPMS_DS" type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource">
    <properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVERNAME:1521:DBNAME" password="{xor}blablabla" user="MY_USER"/>
</dataSource>
```

Sadly, Liberty Profile doesn't seem to provide a way to test the DB connection, but everything seems correctly configured (I can assure the credentials are correct, as well as the server name and port). What am I missing here?

**EDIT #1**

Following njr's suggestion, I've performed a thread dump and here is a summary:

```
-  waiting on com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.EventSemaphore@737eaefc
-  waiting on com.ibm.ws.objectManager.FileLogOutput$FlushHelper@19d51071
-  waiting on com.ibm.ws.objectManager.FileLogOutput$NotifyHelper@2fa0da91
-  waiting on com.ibm.ws.objectManager.ObjectManagerState$CheckpointHelper@5b0919fc
-  waiting on com.ibm.ws.sib.msgstore.persistence.dispatcher.SpillDispatcher$DispatchingLock@1620db94
   (8 Occorrences, but different instances)
   ...
-  waiting on com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.BoundedBuffer$GetQueueLock@c8a05b6
   (56 Occorrences, but different instances)
   ...
-  waiting on java.lang.Object@4c1d5897
-  waiting on java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@5448da4c
-  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@f91b025
-  waiting on java.util.LinkedList@5b213416
-  waiting on java.util.LinkedList@6cb46e1f
-  waiting on java.util.TaskQueue@f50561c
   (14 Occorrences, but different instances)
   ...
-  waiting on java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference@5476d077
-  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@4da17c93
-  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@513339c6
-  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@5dc2ae0f
-  waiting on org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread@236970be
-  waiting on org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread@6dfdd5
-  waiting on org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread@72ce4e1c
-  blocked on com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableTMHelper@5748c911
-  blocked on com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableTMHelper@5748c911
```

Can someone help me to interpret this?

**EDIT #2**

Here's where the complete stack trace of the blocked threads:

```
LargeThreadPool-thread-148 [217] (BLOCKED)
   com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableTMHelper.start line: 63
   com.ibm.tx.jta.util.TxTMHelper.start line: 461
   com.ibm.tx.util.TMHelper.start line: 74
   com.ibm.tx.jta.util.TxTMHelper.checkTMState line: 500
   com.ibm.tx.util.TMHelper.checkTMState line: 116
   com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.registerResourceInfo line: 270
   com.ibm.ws.transaction.services.TransactionManagerService.registerResourceInfo line: 260
   com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.registerXAResourceInfo line: 2537
   com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.<init> line: 509
   com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManagerServiceImpl.getConnectionManager line: 407
   com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManagerServiceImpl.getConnectionManager line: 54
   com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.AbstractConnectionFactoryService.createResource line: 146
   com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.IndirectJndiLookupObjectFactory.createResourceWithFilter line: 346
   com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.IndirectJndiLookupObjectFactory.createResource line: 319
   com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.IndirectJndiLookupObjectFactory.getObjectInstance line: 133
   com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.IndirectJndiLookupObjectFactory.getObjectInstance line: 99
   com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObjectInstance line: 1556
   com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObject line: 1433
   com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObject line: 1389
   com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.naming.InjectionJavaColonHelper.getObjectInstance line: 116
   com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaURLContext.lookup line: 333
   com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaURLContext.lookup line: 371
   org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup line: 161
   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup line: 417
   pt.sibs.epms.persistence.utils.EntityManagerFactoryController.jndiLookupUsed line: 264
   pt.sibs.epms.persistence.utils.EntityManagerFactoryController.checkConfiguration line: 115
   pt.sibs.epms.persistence.utils.EntityManagerFactoryController.<init> line: 95
   pt.sibs.epms.persistence.utils.EntityManagerFactoryController.<init> line: 51
   pt.sibs.epms.persistence.utils.EntityManagerFactoryController$SingletonHolder.<clinit> line: 81
   pt.sibs.epms.persistence.utils.EntityManagerFactoryController.getInstance line: 88
   pt.sibs.epms.util.logging.LoggerConfiguration.<clinit> line: 33
   pt.sibs.epms.ecc.renderer.HtmlFormRenderer.<clinit> line: 25
   java.lang.Class.forName0 line: not available [native method]
   java.lang.Class.forName line: 348
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebApp.addClassToHandlesTypesStartupSet line: 1104
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebApp.scanForHandlesTypesClasses line: 1038
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers line: 2493
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize line: 1037
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize line: 6545
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp line: 466
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler line: 264
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler line: 329
   com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl.discriminate line: 251
   com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready line: 301
   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination line: 471
   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest line: 405
   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest line: 285
   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpICLReadCallback.complete line: 66
   com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete line: 1777
   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete line: 504
   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO line: 574
   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun line: 929
   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run line: 1018
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker line: 1142
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run line: 617
   java.lang.Thread.run line: 745
```

And the second thread:

```
LargeThreadPool-thread-3 [33] (BLOCKED)
   com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableTMHelper.start line: 63
   com.ibm.tx.jta.util.TxTMHelper.start line: 461
   com.ibm.tx.util.TMHelper.start line: 74
   com.ibm.tx.jta.util.TxTMHelper.checkTMState line: 500
   com.ibm.tx.util.TMHelper.checkTMState line: 116
   com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.begin line: 167
   com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.beginGlobalTx line: 593
   com.ibm.ejs.csi.Required.preInvoke line: 56
   com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.preInvoke line: 222
   com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvokeActivate line: 3176
   com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.EjbPreInvoke line: 2576
   com.ibm.ejs.container.TimedObjectWrapper.invokeCallback line: 84
   com.ibm.ejs.container.TimerNpRunnable.doWork line: 196
   com.ibm.ejs.container.TimerNpRunnable.run line: 103
   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call line: 511
   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run line: 266
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker line: 1142
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run line: 617
   java.lang.Thread.run line: 745
```

**Edit #3**

The thread that is WAITING and, apparently, blocking the other two threads:

```
LargeThreadPool-thread-38 [103] (WAITING)
   java.lang.Object.wait line: not available [native method]
   java.lang.Object.wait line: 502
   com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.EventSemaphore.waitEvent line: 71
   com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.waitForReplayCompletion line: 1273
   com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TxRecoveryAgentImpl.initiateRecovery line: 413
   com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.RecoveryDirectorImpl.directInitialization line: 751
   com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.RecoveryDirectorImpl.driveLocalRecovery line: 1240
   com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.RecLogServiceImpl.start line: 125
   com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableTMHelper.start line: 130
   com.ibm.tx.jta.util.TxTMHelper.start line: 461
   com.ibm.tx.util.TMHelper.start line: 74
   com.ibm.tx.jta.util.TxTMHelper.checkTMState line: 500
   com.ibm.tx.util.TMHelper.checkTMState line: 116
   com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.begin line: 167
   com.ibm.ws.transaction.services.TransactionManagerService.begin line: 281
   com.ibm.ws.concurrent.persistent.internal.PersistentExecutorImpl$PollingTask.run line: 2239
```

Not sure if it is related, but ffdc is showing the following exception:

```
------Start of DE processing------ = [09-11-2016 14:41:09:006 GMT]
Exception = com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.LogIncompatibleException
Source = com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.LogHandle
probeid = 326
Stack Dump = com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.LogIncompatibleException
    at com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.LogFileHandle.fileOpen(LogFileHandle.java:522)
    at com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.LogHandle.openLog(LogHandle.java:324)
    at com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.MultiScopeRecoveryLog.openLog(MultiScopeRecoveryLog.java:602)at com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.RecoveryLogImpl.openLog(RecoveryLogImpl.java:77)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.run(RecoveryManager.java:1835)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Both of the dataSource configurations that you tried look valid.  I would recommend capturing a thread dump to see what is happening on the lookup path,

    server dump <your-server-name>

[http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_setup_dump_server.html][1]

  [1]: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_setup_dump_server.html

Comment: Once you have the dump, look in
introspections/ThreadInfoIntrospector.txt
and locate the thread stack where your application code does the lookup.  You should be able to see if it's stuck in Liberty code or in the Oracle JDBC driver.

Sometimes it can be helpful to capture multiple dumps in sequence to observe if it is stuck in exactly the same place or if it's stuck in a loop.  If there is a deadlock (not sure why this would ever be the case for a simple lookup), you'll need to look at what other threads are doing as well.

Please feel free to attach the thread dump for investigation.

Comment: @njr, thanks for your suggestions, I'll try to do just that and, once I've the data, I'll attach it here.

Comment: @njr, I've added a summary of the thread dump, there are no deadlocks, but it shows two blocked threads, is that supposed to happen?

Comment: it's not clear from that information where the blockage is happening. Try to look at the stack trace snapshots.  We are looking for the thread that has your JNDI lookup somewhere in the stack so we can see where in the WLP code the lookup is blocking.

Comment: @njr, could you please check my last edit? Is this the info you're mentioning? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, thanks for posting the stack.  It suggests the possibility of a deadlock, but to confirm that, we need the other thread that is involved in the deadlock.  Is there any chance one of the other thread stacks has both
com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableTMHelper.start and com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.AbstractConnectionFactoryService.createResource in it, but in the opposite order as the stack from Edit #2?  If so could you post that thread stack?  Thanks!

Comment: @njr, I've attached the second stack trace. Thanks.

Comment: Can `com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet` be the culprit?

Comment: The second thread "LargeThreadPool-thread-3 [33]" wouldn't be the culprit.  We need to identify the other thread that holds the lock on com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableTMHelper (and which is presumably blocked attempting to obtain a lock that is held by one of these two threads that you have identified).  Is it possible to easily attach all of the thread stacks?  Or at least all of the blocked ones?

Comment: @njr, I've added more information, if you have a chance please take a look. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Given that the blocking/waiting is more in the transaction manager as opposed the original deadlock that I originally suspected might have occurred between the connection factory and recovery path, I asked a coworker with more experience in the transaction manager to have a look at this.

Comment: @njr, thanks again for your help, I'll wait for some feedback from your coworker. Just to add some more info, the application is working fine in WebSphere 9 Full Profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Edit #3, the thread that is waiting in

**com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.waitForReplayCompletion**

will have spawned another recoveryManager thread who's role is to access the transaction log files in your flesystem. That other thread Should do the minimal amount of file processing necessary before signalling to the waiting thread that it may continue. Can you see another thread with a stack containing

**com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.run** ?

I am concerned about the LogIncompatibleException. It suggests that the transaction log files on your filesystem are
corrupt. This should not cause the server to hang and I believe you've hit a product defect.

If you need to make progress quickly, it may be appropriate in your scenario to delete the transaction log files. 
Please note that this is something we only suggest to customers with extreme care as the transaction logs ensure 
the integrity of distributed transactions. In a production environment we'd generally recommend that such action
is only taken under the guidance of IBM Level 3 Service. But in a test/evaluation scenario it can be applicable.

The Liberty transaction log info is stored in the /wlp/usr/servers//tranlog 
directory. If appropriate the tranlog and partnerlog subdirectories may be deleted and the server restarted.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for your reply. There are 112 threads and none of them contains `com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.run` on the stack trace. The exceptions occur every time I start the application, not the server, and happen 3 times. There aren´t other related messages on the log file.

Comment: You're right. In your config the Transaction Manager is started when Liberty determines that it is first needed - that is when your application is invoked. I think that you've hit a Liberty product defect. Would it be possible to gather some trace? You'd need to add the following to your server.xml file,

Comment: <logging traceSpecification="Transaction=all:logservice=all=enabled:*=info=enabled"/>

Comment: That will give us the information we need to fix the defect (need to find a way of getting the trace file to me). It seems likely that the transaction log files in your filesystem have somehow been corrupted. So, I would love to see that trace but after gathering that, if you need to make progress quickly, it may be appropriate in your scenario to delete the transaction log files. Please note that this is something we only suggest to customers with extreme care as the transaction logs ensure the integrity of distributed transactions. But in a test/evaluation scenario it can be appropriate.

Comment: how can I hand you the file (trace.log)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The Liberty transaction log info is stored in the <LiBERTY_INSTALL>/wlp/usr/servers/<your_server_name>/tranlog directory. If appropriate the tranlog and partnerlog subdirectories may be deleted.